# How to make transition effect like Podcast application?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've known that there are 4 types of transition effect: horizon, vertical, flip, curve.

But, what I want is the transition effect used in Podcast application.
It's similar with the flip effect, but it's slightly different. As you can see the picture below, it looks like it has volume; so it's more spectacular.

[image]

How can I make a transition effect like this?

Comment: You can upload the picture somewhere else and post the link in your question

Comment: It looks a lot less impressive in freeze frame, doesn't it? The perspective doesn't look right.

Answer (score 1):

The animation is probably done with three separate views - the outgoing, the side, and the incoming. The anchor point of each view's layer can be set such that they all rotate around the same central vertical axis, which is half of the side's width inset into the screen. The side view is initially rotated to M_PI_2, the back view to M_PI.

All three layers can then be rotated by M_PI. This will give the appearance of a rotating solid object. The main view's sublayer transform should be adjusted to give some perspective to the rotation. This involves setting the .m34 value to a small number, there are plenty of examples of this around on the web.

**all angles in radians, some may need to be negative, this is just an explanation of the principles*